# Why are comments enabled on my content types in Simpletests?

Tags: comments, testing

When I run Simpletest, it's showing comment forms at the bottom of all the nodes, even though I don't even have the comment module enabled, nor permissions assigned for it. These comment forms showing up in tests is interfering with my tests and I need to disable them, but I don't know how since I never enabled them in the first place.

Comment: Are you testing for yourself, or are you trying to make drupal.org testbot to accept your patch? If it's the later option, tests **should** fail when new code conflicts with core functionality, and comments are in core.

Comment: This is not for a patch, this is for integration testing a site. My code doesn't conflict with core functionality, but it does create UI elements like "Save" buttons that it's hard to test for the presence/absence of if there's another random "Save" button that doesn't exist in production.

Comment: Also, these are custom content types that are generated in the test by enabling a Features module, so their settings should be identical to the settings I see on production. I am able to wipe out my database completely and resurrect everything from code without encountering this issue on my dev environment, only in tests does it present an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`module_disable(array('comment'));`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) inside `setup()` does the trick.